# Why biplanes are not used in modern high speed aircrafts?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft

Explain why the high speed and commercial air crafts are monoplanes why not biplanes?

Comment: I think this may be off topic here, but it might fit on [aviation.SE].

Comment: Too much drag with biplane wings and the support wires between the wings.

Comment: Why not triplanes?

Comment: Biplanes are aerodynamically horrid.  *But*, since you can  consider the upper and lower wings as a beam and since both the strength and stiffness of beams go up rapidly with thickness, biplanes are superb if you have to make an aeroplane out of materials such as wood, wire and cloth.  When better materials (aluminium) and better manufacturing techniques became available, biplanes went away.  Note that beam theory is a large and important subject area.

Comment: Early planes, and even the current Waco and Pitts, had good reasons for multiple wings. It's easy to strengthen them with cross-bracing, and the overall width (and roll inertia) can be reduced, all good for aerobatics. But, with higher speeds, reduced drag becomes paramount, and all that bracing adds drag. Also, the fewer wings there are, the simpler the structure.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of the biplane wings are:

(1) 2x times bigger surface, thus roughly 2x times bigger elevating force

The disadvantages are numerous:

(2) (Roughly) double drag (double required fuel)

(3) (Roughly) double service, etc. costs

Now the drag, and also the elevating force, depends (roughly) quadratically on the speed. In the ancient times, the speed of the planes were at most some hundreds of km/h. Now they near the speed of the sound.

Contrary the misconception, most of the fuel of the planes isn't used for to hold the plane in the air. It is used against the drag.

Biplanes were useful as holding the plane in the air was a big engineering challenge, because their speed was slow. Now the problem is the drag.

Thus, also a monoplane is enough to hold the plane in the air, and it is even needed, because the drag have to be minimized.

---

*Extension:*

> Why does a biplane have to have double the wing surface and double the
>   drag? Why couldn't the size of each of the two sets of wings be scaled
>   down so that both the total wing surface and the total drag of a
>   biplane are similar to a comparably sized mono-wing airplane?

The drag is a very complex, nonlinear thing, but (very) roughly it depends linearly on the cross-section. Most important non-linear effect that we need to have a drop-like streamlined form, as the form of the plane deviates from it, we will have higher drag. In extreme case we can call it parachute. Thus, biplanes have higher drag even with the same cross-section as a monoplane. And majority of the costs of the planes is coming from the fuel, and the majority of the fuel is going to handle the drag.

Included from @SamuelWeir 's comment:

Consider also that not the wings are doubled, but we also have additional drag from the wires and trusses between the wings.

Notable [link](http://www.popularmechanics.com/flight/a7517/the-return-of-the-supersonic-biplane-7505124/) about supersonic biplanes.

Comment: "The advantage of the biplane wings are: (1) 2x times bigger surface, thus roughly 2x times bigger elevating force. The disadvantages are numerous: (2) (Roughly) double drag (double required fuel)..." - Why does a biplane have to have double the wing surface and double the drag? Why couldn't the size of each of the two sets of wings be scaled down so that both the total wing surface and the total drag of a biplane are similar to a comparably sized mono-wing airplane?

Comment: @SamuelWeir Seems pretty obvious he meant if you just doubled the wing you already had.  I don't see the issue with how he brought it up here.

Comment: @SamuelWeir The drag is a very complex, nonlinear thing, but (very) roughly it depends linearly on the cross-section. Most important non-linear effect that we need to have a drop-like streamlined form, as the form of the plane deviates from it, we will have higher drag. In extreme case we can call it *parachute*. Thus, biplanes have higher drag even with the same cross-section as a monoplane. And majority of the costs of the planes is coming from the fuel, and the majority of the fuel is going to handle the drag.

Comment: @JMac - But we're talking here about the inherent pros and cons of the biplane design versus the mono-wing design. Having double the wing surface area or double the drag are not inherent pros and cons in the biplane versus mono-wing argument because that all depends on the wing sizes.

Comment: @SamuelWeir And he showed why doubling up the wing doesn't help.  As far as I can tell that was the intent of the question.  Scaling it down doesn't make this apply any less.

Comment: @JMac- I didn't read the question that way. I interpreted it as asking why the biplane design concept is not attractive for modern high-speed aircraft, not why it is unattractive to simply double up the wings of a monoplane design.

Comment: @SamuelWeir I think the answer answers both interpretation.

Comment: @peterh:"The drag is a very complex, nonlinear thing, but (very) roughly it depends linearly on the cross-section." - Thanks for the info, peterh. I think with the biplanes of old, the big problem was the additional drag due to all of the wires and trusses between the wings. But perhaps with modern materials and engineering the situation has changed. I googled "supersonic biplanes" and came up with a few links including this one: http://www.popularmechanics.com/flight/a7517/the-return-of-the-supersonic-biplane-7505124/

Comment: @SamuelWeir Wow, it is an interesting link! I injected this into the post.

Comment: @SamuelWeir But he basically addressed that.  With a bi-plane you could fit twice the wings in the same space to increase the lift.  The problem comes from the drag being increased.  The questions of "why don't we use bi-planes" seems quite similar to me to "what happens if we double up the wings (and scale them)".  The answer still stems from the fact that you're increasing the drag surface area while increasing the lift area; and that increase in drag area is a big problem with quick moving planes.  It's not like you can really make the second wing thinner if you expect the same force.